# Interesting observation for SQL WHERE EXISTS in subqueires

Tags: sql, select, subquery, where-clause, exists

I'd like to know if someone can explain why the following occurs:

I have the following Table which I made up. It has 2 columns "A" and "B":

```
A       B
==========
1,      11
2,      12
3,      13
4,      14
5,      15
6,      16
7,      17
8,      18
9,      19
```

If I run the following Query :-

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT A,B FROM Table_1) T1
WHERE EXISTS 
    (SELECT 'X' FROM Table_1 WHERE A = 3)
```

I get the entire table. This I understand cause the EXISTS clause checks if it finds a single row in a statement which it does

However, If I run the following query, I only get a portion of the table

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT A,B FROM Table_1) T1
WHERE EXISTS 
    (SELECT 'X' FROM Table_1 WHERE T1.A=3 OR T1.A=4)
```

The portional results are as follows

```
A     B
========
3,    13
4,    14
```

Can anyone explain why this happens?

Comment: You are probably confusing yourself by adding an extra `or` condition to the second query. That is not what is causing the behavior you see. It is the fact that you use `T1` as a prefix in the where clause that makes the difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's break down what you're actually asking the database server to do.

`SELECT * FROM` - get all fields. I'm going to ignore this bit from now on, since it's not important.

`(SELECT A,B FROM Table_1) T1` - get all rows from the table, and name that result set "T1".

`WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 'X' FROM Table_1 WHERE A = 3)` - Select, INDEPENDENT of the above, all rows from the table. This happens once per row in the table - but always does the same thing, since `T1` is not used in the subquery. If one of the rows of the table has A=3 (always the case), do no restriction. Otherwise, discard that particular `T1` (this does not happen here).

`WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 'X' FROM Table_1 WHERE T1.A=3 OR T1.A=4)` - this one is tricky. You're making a second selection of all rows from the table, but you're restricting by this condition: `T1.A=3 OR T1.A=4`. This condition is based on the result of `T1` - but that's not the whole table, just a *particular* row. When you say `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE mytable.A=3`, you don't mean "select all rows of mytable if some row has A=3", you only mean to select those particular rows where that is true. So, the subquery `SELECT 'X' FROM Table_1 WHERE T1.A=3 OR T1.A=4` contains either no rows or all the rows in `Table_1`, depending on which value is in `T1.A`. Because you use `EXISTS`, you get true for all rows and false for none.

That's why you get different results - your subquery is performed once per row in `Table_1`. In the first case, it always contains one row. In the second case, it contains either no rows or all nine, depending on the particular row of `Table_1` contained in `T1`.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably easier if you remove some of the subqueries. Your queries essentially come down to the following:

Query 1: Select all records from `Table_1` where `true`. This is because there are `A` fields in `Table_1` that contain 3 or 4.

Query 2: Select all records from `Table_1` where `A` equals 3 or `A` equals 4

Expressed in SQL, your queries can be simplified to

```
SELECT * FROM Table_1
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM Table_1
WHERE A IN (3,4)
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe it would be examining the current row of T1 to see if A=3 or A=4, similar to if you wrote:

```
SELECT * FROM 
  (SELECT A,B FROM Table_1) T1
WHERE A=3 OR A=4;
```

Answer (score 1):

Wow, cool.

You have a little extra SQL in there.  What you're really doing is:

```
 SELECT * FROM Table_1 T1 WHERE EXISTS 
    (SELECT 'X' FROM Table_1 WHERE T1.A = 3 OR T1.A = 4)
```

So what's happening?

As you read each row of Table_1 as T1, the engine evaluates the sub-select in order to decide whether the row from T1 should be included in the result set.

On the first row, where T1.A is 1, then T1.A = 3 is `FALSE` and T1.A = 4 is `FALSE`, so the sub-select fails.  That row is not included in the result set.

Same when A = 2.  The row with A = 2 is not included.

But for the next two rows (T1.A of 3 and 4) at least one side of the `OR` evaluates to `TRUE` and the sub-select succeeds.  So those two rows are included.

When you hit T1.A of 5, and for the rest of the table, the sub-select fails.

Comment: Oops, cut-and-paste error from the original question's SQL.  Fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

There are always multiple ways to write the same thing in SQL. For example this

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT A,B FROM Table_1) T1
```

...may be rewritten as this:

```
SELECT A, B
  FROM Table_1
```

The latter is simpler and I see no reason to prefer the former. Rewriting your first query accordingly

```
SELECT A, B
  FROM Table_1
 WHERE EXISTS (
               SELECT 'X' 
                 FROM Table_1 
                WHERE A = 3
              );
```

I've removed the correlation name `T1` because it server no purpose. The subquery does not reference its 'outer' table expression so each appearance `Table_1` does not need to be disambiguated.

I think you understand what is going on here: if one or more rows in `Table_1` satisfy the search condition `A = 3` then the entire table is returned, otherwise the empty set is returned. While it is a valid query it is not often a very useful construct.

For your second query, however, at least one correlation name is required because the subquery does reference its outer table:

```
SELECT A, B
  FROM Table_1 T1
 WHERE EXISTS (
               SELECT 'X' 
                 FROM Table_1 T2
                WHERE T1.A IN (3, 4)
              );
```

Again this is semantically equivalent to your second query. Note that I've given the apperance of `Table_1` in the subquery the correlation name `T2` but `T2` does not appear in the subquery's `WHERE` clause. Because `T2` is not being used, we can remove the subquery (hence the need for correlation names) entirely:

```
SELECT A, B
  FROM Table_1
 WHERE A IN (3, 4);
```

It's worth pointing out that the ability for a subquery to reference an 'outer' table expression is usually exploited as a 'correlated subquery' i.e. the search condition (`WHERE` clause) involves both 'inner' and 'outer' tables (your second query's search condition involves the 'outer' table only).

Using the [usual parts and suppliers database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suppliers_and_Parts_database), here is an example of a correlated subquery to implement a [semijoin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6449544/findout-duplicate-rows-in-a-table-while-inserting/6450663#6450663) to find suppliers (`S`) who supply (`SP`) at least one part:

```
SELECT SNO, SNAME
  FROM S
 WHERE EXISTS (
               SELECT *
                 FROM SP
                WHERE SP.SNO = S.SNO
              );
```

Note the subquery's search condition relates the 'outer' table `SP` to the 'inner' table `S`. Also, the projection `SELECT SNO, SNAME` in the 'outer' table does not require the inclusion of the correlation name `S` because `SP` from the 'outer' table is not in scope for the 'inner' table.