# Error when execute SQL query for relation algebra division in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-algebra

I have 3 tables (provider, provider_has_product, product):
[image]

(Original here: http://content.screencast.com/users/Maksold/folders/Jing/media/4e6de435-eeac-4602-95e0-2a1b0b4876ad/2012-01-18_0851.png)

I tried division operation by this code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `provider_has_product`.`provider_id` FROM `provider_has_product` WHERE NOT EXIST
 (SELECT * FROM `product` WHERE NOT EXIST
  (SELECT * FROM `provider_has_product` A1 WHERE 
     A1.`provider_id` = `provider_has_product`.`provider_id` AND
     A1.`product_id` = `product`.`id`))
```

But it dosn't work. It shows: `Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT * FROM`product`WHERE NOT EXIST
          (SELECT * FROM`provider_has_p' at line 2`

How make division on MySQL and correct this error.

Comment: My concept of "division" was the operation inverse to multiplication, i.e. something like "10/3 = 3.333" :-?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario: Division is one of Codd's original operators. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6449544/findout-duplicate-rows-in-a-table-while-inserting/6450663#6450663).

Comment: Oops... Something I failed to study. Thanks for the tip, @onedaywhen

Answer (score 3):

Check for a typo. I'm pretty sure it's `EXISTS`, not `EXIST`