# Mysql Intersect query

Tags: mysql, select, group-by, distinct

I have 3 mysql table subjects, exams and exams_subjects. subject contains subject ids, exam contains exam ids and exam_subjects contains subjects ids and exam ids. I want to write a mysql query to get an output of subject ids from  exams_subjects table that are common to all exam ids. ie the intersection of subject ids for different exam ids. How can I write such a query ?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT subjectid 
FROM exam_subjects 
WHERE examid IN (SELECT examid FROM exams) 
GROUP BY subjectid 
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(examid) FROM exams);
```

I got this with the help of a similar question in stack overflow [How to do intersection on a composition table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9775593/how-to-do-intersection-on-a-composition-table?rq=1)